# Connecting to Amazon SES with Django on Openshift

Tags: django, openshift, amazon-ses

I am trying to access amazon SES from openshift using a django based app.

The app works properly when run from my development system (assuming firewall is not block SMTP connection) but does not succeed when run from openshift link after I push to the openshift servers. I can telnet to the SES server from the openshift console.

Is there an openshift or SES setting that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

There is a community blog http://atodorov.org/blog/2013/02/28/email-logging-django-redhat-openshift-amazon-ses/ that talks about how to use Amazon SES with OpenShift. Please make sure your configuration is correct as shown in that blog. Also read https://www.openshift.com/forums/express/missing-email-on-500-ise-w-django

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I have installed django_ses and now seem to be connecting to the server on my local development machine, but now I am getting an "SESAddressNotVerified" error. I was able to send an email via the python shell through SES, it seems that the app still has some setting that I have fouled up. I have set the SERVER_EMAIL, is there any other setting that I am missing?

Comment: I have figured out how to solve this problem and am now running both locally and off of the openshift server. After installing boto and django SES (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ses) on both my local machine and on the openshift server AND setting AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT correctly I can send email through SES.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to solve this problem and am now running both locally and off of the openshift server. After installing boto and django SES (pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ses) on both my local machine and on the openshift server AND setting AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT correctly I can send email through SES.